# sql distinct select from multiple select

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the best way to join the following three select and to get non duplicated contact.id ?

Any idea ?

```
 SELECT distinct ct.id
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct 
  left join [Customer].[dbo].[HN_Customer_ids] hnids 
       on ct.id = hnids.contact_id 
  left join [CustomerTransactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] trh 
       on trh.Customer_ID = hnids.HN_customer_id
 where trh.actual_transaction_date > '20120218'
```

Result: 231360

```
  SELECT count(distinct(contact_id))
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
  where ( created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000' or modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000') 
    AND
```

Result: 167128

```
 SELECT distinct aaa.id
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] aaa 
  left join [Customer].[dbo].[Wifinity_Devices] bbb 
       on aaa.wifinity_uniqueID = bbb.[CustomerUniqueID]
  and startconnection > '2012-02-17'
```

Result: 77290

Comment: Which result is the "correct" result, according to what you want to know?

Comment: You should join them according to the way your business rules are modeled by your database, so as to produce your desired results, which right now, only you know.

Comment: You should try to be precise when talking about "joining". In this case it appears you want to combine the lists in a union (a horizontal "join") but it wasn't absolutely clear without more information from you.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  On the first that where changes the left join into a regular join. On the second you have a hanging and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union`.  So:

```
SELECT ct.id
FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct join
     [Customer].[dbo].[HN_Customer_ids] hnids
     on ct.id = hnids.contact_id join
     [CustomerTransactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] trh
     on trh.Customer_ID = hnids.HN_customer_id
WHERE trh.actual_transaction_date > '20120218'
UNION
SELECT contact_id
FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
WHERE (created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000' or
       modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT aaa.id
FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] aaa ;
```

The `left join`s are unnecessary in the first and third queries.  In the first, the `where` undoes the `left join` anyway.  In the third, you are choosing an `id` from the first table, and the `left join` does no filtering.

Comment: I think startConnection is in the joined table on the third one.

Comment: Doesn't the 3rd query cancel the first one out?

Comment: Yeah, it would. Except that I think the third one is also missing a condition that also required the join.

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . No.  The condition is in the `on` clause.  Hence, it will not affect the rows being fetched from the first table.

Comment: You're right. The line wrap threw me. Then gvee is right too. The entire query is pointless as the third query returns _all_ the contacts regardless.

Answer (score 1):

use union

```
SELECT ct.id
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct 
  left join [Customer].[dbo].[HN_Customer_ids] hnids on ct.id = hnids.contact_id 
  left join [CustomerTransactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] trh on trh.Customer_ID = hnids.HN_customer_id
  where trh.actual_transaction_date > '20120218'
union 
 SELECT  contact_id 
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
  where ( created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000' or modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000')
union 
 SELECT aaa.id
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] aaa left join [Customer].[dbo].[Wifinity_Devices] bbb on aaa.wifinity_uniqueID = bbb.[CustomerUniqueID]
  and startconnection > '2012-02-17'
```

Comment: Not that it matters a lot but the unions make the `distinct`s unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all queries run against the same Contact table, your use of left outer join is effectively causing the third query to return *all* the contacts. Unless the second query can add contact_ids not found in the Contact table, the end result is equivalent to:

```
select /* distinct, if not a pk */ contact_id from Customer.dbo.Contact
```

Your row counts suggest that maybe these are actually tables from different databases. Is that the case?